# use find and grep to find lines that contain some string and don't contain other string from files

Tags: grep, find, xargs

First, I try the following code

```
find . -name "*.cfg" | xargs grep "good"|grep -v "^\#"
```

In the current folder, I get the list with the file name's extension is "cfg". Then I want to search the contents to find lines containing the "good" but not begin with "#" .
But my code doesn't work. Is there something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
find . -name "*.cfg" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -E '^([^#].*|)good'
```

Note that I switched to `-print0` to avoid problems with file names
containing white space.

Then I filter lines containing `good` but not starting with `#` in a
single regexp. The left alternative (`[^#].*`) matches lines that
begin with a non-`#` character, wheres the right alternative (empty)
allows matching lines that begin with `good`.

Using a single regexp, rather than two as in your question, allows us
to let GNU grep print file names (which it will do if more than one
file is provided by `find`). Adding `grep -v ^...` in a second step
would fail to match the beginning of the file's lines.

Comment: Thank you, I like this code, because it shows which file it contains the string.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that this was a reason for using a single regexp: the code in your question will not work when more than one file is matched by the first call to grep, because then GNU grep will prepend file names, preventing the call to `grep -v` from properly matching start-of-line patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Useless use of xargs (if your find has -exec):

```
find . -name "*.cfg" -exec egrep "^[^#]*good" {} +
```

The caret doesn't need to be masked - I don't know any circumstance where it has to be. 
But it isn't of harm and your whole command works for me.

Comment: You should use `execplus` instead of `exec`.

Comment: @schily: Why? Execplus has to be pretty new - I've never seen it before. I'm using find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2. Or do you mean -exec ... + ? Well, you can, yes. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. :)

Comment: `execplus` exists since 1989, `gfind` seems to have overslept the last 20 years of UNIX development.

Comment: `execplus` is the common way of naming `-exec ... +` since David Korn introduced it in 1989.